# How do Nodes work in java?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

Ok, I have a class called CarNode:

```
public class CarNode {
    private Car car;
    private CarNode node;
}
```

and a copy constructor:

```
public CarList(CarList list) {
    CarNode element = list.head;
    CarNode node = new CarNode();
    this.head = node;

    while(element != null) {
        node.setCar(element.getCar());
        element = element.getNode();

        if(element != null) {
            node.setNode(new CarNode());
            node = element;
        }
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is how **element** can get the value of another car node through element.getNode(), but you need to write node.setNode() and node.setCar() for **node**... I am confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CarNode has a variable, node, that is also a CarNode; this means a CarNode object can contain a reference to another CarNode object.  `element` is a variable that contains a reference to a CarNode.  The code `element = element.getNode()` assigns the reference within the element object to the element reference itself (or null, if the node within element is null).

In order to set a value on the node element within a `CarNode`, you call `setNode(elementReference)`, giving rise to the syntax `node.setNode(new CarNode());`.

Does this answer your question?  I realize it may be hard to explain what you want to ask, but in fact we don't have a very clear question yet.

--- addendum

I'll try to answer your comments here, since more comments are limited in space and formatting.

I think you're confusing the "object" with the "object reference".  You can think of the object as a block of memory somewhere in the program, and the object reference as the address of that block.  Consider the statement:

```
CarNode myCar = new CarNode();
```

You have created a block of memory with `new CarNode()`, and `myCar` now refers to it.  If you were to now execute the statement `CarNode secondCar = myCar;`, you would have a second reference to the same object, i.e., to the same block of memory.  Any changes made to the object/block of memory would be reflected in both myCar and secondCar.

Your "copy constructor" as you call it, is confusing to me also.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  Usually a copy constructor creates one or more objects that contain the same data as an original object or set of objects.  First of all, if the original list pointer is null, this will throw a NullPointerException on the first line.  You create a first node and set it to be the head, that's fine, but the `node = element;` statement is just wrong.  `node` holds a node you are creating to put in your new list, and `element` holds an element from the original list.

Comment: I am kinda confused, because it's my first time manipulating linkedlists. So if we write CarNode node = element (in the 4th line), we basically created a clone of the head of the list? But if we want to just change the node value without changing the car value we write: node.setNode(new CarNode());? How does creating a new car object set the node to another node within the LinkedList though? and is the last line correct?

Comment: creating a clone means that there are two CarNodes referring to the same next CarNodes right?

Comment: I've added a bit more explanation to the original answer; hope it helps.  The presence of a 'head' in your list is complicating the logic needed to copy the list.